# image resolution loss when try to crop image from camera view and gallery

Tags: android, image-processing, resolution, android-image-capture

At my project i have image crop function when user change profile .
Everything is going fine but when i try to crop the image after select photo 
the photo change to blur and loss resolution . I use Edmodo cropper.
is there have any solution or a better image cropper. Here is my code ...

```
 private void startCrop(Uri imageUri) {
    CropImage.activity(imageUri)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.OFF)
            .setMinCropWindowSize(200, 200)
            .setFixAspectRatio(true)
            .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,                          R.color.colorTransparent))
            .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.RECTANGLE)
            .setBorderLineColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setBorderLineThickness(2)
            .start(this);
}
```

Comment: try this library https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper.